# Selenium : org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException:

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

This is how the HTML looks like.

```
<select name="ctl00$bodyContent$ddl_Territory" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$bodyContent$ddl_Territory\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="ctl00_bodyContent_ddl_Territory" class="select2-container" style="margin-left: 3%;">
    <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
    <option value="675">ALASKA AK (OCRGA061A) - HCP</option>
    <option value="271">ALBANY GA (OCBDB041A) - HCP</option>
    <option value="125">ALBANY NY (OCBAA031A) - HCP</option>
    <option value="126">ALBANY NY (OCBAA032A) - HCP</option>
    <option value="426">ALBANY NY (OCRAA031A) - HCP</option>
    ....
    <option value="427">ALBANY NY (OCRAA031A) - HOSPITAL</option>
```

Automation code that keeps failing -

```
Select territory = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$bodyContent$ddl_Territory")));
        System.out.println("selected");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
           // Trying to figure if sleep is required or not.. 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        List<WebElement> optionList = territory.getOptions();
        for (WebElement webElement : optionList) {
            System.out.println(webElement.getText()); //this print nothing..empty line..confused
        }

        territory.selectByIndex(1); //exception thrown here
```

When i call `selectByIndex` i get `org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException:` . I have tried selectByValue etc.. also but of no help. **I am sure that  `territory` points to the correct element because the optionList count is same as the number of options in HTML**. However not sure why the text is not getting printed in Loop and why the exception..

Driver - geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64

TIA!

UPDATE 1: `webElement.isDisplayed()` print `false` for all options. And `getLocation()` prints `0,0` for both X and Y coordinates..

Comment: What are you trying to do here `List<WebElement> optionList = territory.getOptions();`? Thanks

Comment: Wht trying to sleep for 10 secs? `try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }`

Comment: `List<WebElement> optionList = territory.getOptions(); ` I was trying to get the list of options inside the Select and keep them in memory for later purposes..The sleep is something that i am experimenting on.

Comment: can you share a link on which you are working[ if possible ] ? that would be good for understanding your problem. I can try writing script on this.

Comment: Have you tried on any other browser?

Comment: @Rohhit : sorry,  its an internal site..

Comment: @Grasshopper : Even i am doubting that this could be a browser/driver specific issue. https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2668 claims to have fixed it in 49 but its not working for me in 50.0.

Comment: @ayush Have you tried getting at the options directly without using the Select class for printing out the text? Also what does the onChange method do?

Comment: @Grasshopper : Could you please guide me on how to get Options without using Select?

Comment: @Grasshopper IMO, OP's selected `select` tag is not the right tag. Though the options are pulled out of the lot below the `select` tag.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative way to get all the options are as below

```
List<WebElement> optins = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@name='ctl00$bodyContent$ddl_Territory']/options"));
```

Alternate way to Select by visible text

```
driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$bodyContent$ddl_Territory")).sendKeys("ALBANY NY (OCBAA031A) - HCP");
```

Comment: thanks @Gaurang! The alternative way does work..any idea though on why my approach was not working?

Comment: you approach is a standard approach and should work, must be some issue with webdriver or geckdriver or firefox version. You could try changing them.  but if this solves your problem, here you go. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers